# General approach to proof of correctness for wait-free algorithms

Tags: algorithm, concurrency

I have used universal construction to design an algorithm for wait-free binary search trees. I have got linearization points for each of the methods. But I'm not sure on how do I formally prove correctness of this algorithm.

On searching for similar papers, I found that they have proved that the algorithm is wait-free and only generates linearizable executions. Is this condition necessary or sufficient ?

Are there any other formal methods to prove correctness for wait-free algorithms ?

Comment: I think you better ask this question on [cs.se]

Comment: Wait-free and linearizable are orthogonal concepts.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Agreed that they are orthogonal concepts. My question is whether proving the two independently is sufficient for proving correctness.

Comment: @grillSandwich Yes, then you would have a provably wait-free, linearizable data structure, which is the gold standard.

Answer (score 0):

To formally prove something, you need the following:

- Exact definition of the thing you're going to prove. In your case, that might be some kind of predicates that are always correct. I'll give an example:

> For `BlockingQueue` capped with size N, the number of elements in the queue should always be [0, N].
>
> If `BlockingQueue` is empty, the number of times item was added there is equal to number of times it was removed from there.

Okay, we have the definition or/and exact description. Now, there are several ways to prove something about it:

- `Proof by contradiction` method. Consider statement is incorrect and end up with some impossible conclusion. For example, we want to prove `Integer numbers can be negative` point. Let me state:

> All integer numbers are positive.

That leads us to the fact that `-1` is a positive number which is false, so the statement is incorrect, and original statement is proved.

- Prove that for all possible cases the statement is correct by checking all of them (for limited sets), by using [Mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) (for `Сountable` sets), or using some more sophisticated logical statements and ways. More concrete example depends on the theorem we're going to prove.

I would also add that based on my experience, the `Proof by contradiction` method I wrote above is used very often and suitable in many cases, so probably you should consider it first.

Comment: "Wait-free" means that, whenever a process invokes an operation on the shared object, the invocation completes in finitely many steps *of that process* (i.e., there exists no infinite execution where the process takes infinitely many steps but the operation never finishes). "Linearizable" means that, for every execution, there exists a sequential reordering of the operations such that (i) the object has the correct sequential behavior and (ii) the partial order of operations in the execution is respected. Feel free to write a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey. But I cannot use invariants in concurrent programs like sequential ones. Linearizability is used instead, as given here http://cs.brown.edu/~mph/HerlihyW90/p463-herlihy.pdf . Also IMO, generating all possible states is not a very scalable solution for concurrent programs.